# Geolocation redirect to same page on different domain?

Tags: jquery, geolocation

I'm trying to figure out how use geolocation to reidirect people from a .CA domain to a .US domain and keep them on the same page they were viewing. 
For example if I post something to social media such as this: http://www.band-brand.ca/products/the-agonist-machine
US residents who click on that get redirected to the main .US domain. 
How can I allow them to click on that link and just have it change over to the .US domain (http://www.band-brand.US/products/the-agonist-machine)
Here's the basic code I have:

```
     <script>
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    // If the visitor is browsing from United States.
    if (location.country_code === 'US') {
      // Redirect him to the american store.
      window.location.href = 'www.band-brand.us';
    }
  }
} );
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help/advice,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can't change your domain name, without buying one. So, if you want to do that, you would have to buy a hosting plan that has unlimited plans. This will cost much more money, yes, but it achieves your goal.

Also, if you don't want to spend that much money, you can make subdomains, such as `en.example.com`. You can do this if your host provider allows. The cost is still somewhat expensive.

The best way to do this is by just putting the code on `index.html`, then, according to their country, redirect them to `caindex.html`, or such.